# Java get TRUE origin in HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, cors, cross-domain

i'm building rest API, with CORS enabled. Since API have to be accessed form known domains, i have to check if origin of request is in "White listed" domains.

But i have to be 100% sure, that origin of request is really origin, not some modified header.

I found this link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name

About forbidden header names, so i'm asking is this information is OK, nobody can change header origin?

I'm accessing request in Java like this:

```
(HttpServletRequest) request.getHeader("origin")
```

Is this how i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Spring has excellent out-of-box support to handle cross origin request(s) which can be used via xml or java configuration.

Also the configuration can be either global (*via `CorsRegistry`*) or controller specific (*`@CrossOrigin`*) for granular control

Have a look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) and [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) which has good details on how to get started and how it works.